# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. duplicate entry: com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient$1.class

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle, android-multidex

i am getting an error for duplicate entry but I do not know why. This is my build.grade file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.apppartner.androidprogrammertest"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

I believe i have everything right and in place. What do i do?

Comment: @TONY do you mean from the project structure or the line of code from the dependencies?

Comment: it worked! thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove loopj library if the project compiled correctly then u need to check if u have another library or jar contain same classes with loopj

Comment: How do you conditionally remove the loopj library if it compiled correctly?

Comment: loopj contain classes and another library contain same classes and that cause this issue obviously

Answer (score 0):

This solution has worked for me.

1.- Remove dependency compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'.

If you use some classes from httpclient, check your import classes, you will see that imports correspond to package cz.msebera.android, then you can replace dependecy android-async-http for cz.msebera.android

```
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.2'
```

I hope this help.

Answer (score -1):

You could remove the AsyncHttpClient.java from the com/loopj/http folder and then rebuild the project. I'm sure new errors would occur regarding other duplicated java files...all u need is to delete them one by one until you could successfully build the apk.